# What ports does SQL Server use on Linux?

Tags: sql-server, linux, network

What ports does SQL Server use on Linux? I want to be sure I'm forwarding the ports required when I run it in a container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the defaults, there are two ports SQL Server listens on which can be verified with `netstat -ln`,

- `ms-sql-s` **TCP 1433** for the server
- `ms-sql-m` **TCP 1434** for the Dedicated Administrator Connection which by default is enabled for local connections on `127.0.0.1` only. For more information see ["*remote admin connections Server Configuration Option*"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/remote-admin-connections-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017)

While my install was only listening for TCP connections, `/etc/services` shows entries for UDP too,

```
ms-sql-s        1433/tcp                        # Microsoft SQL Server
ms-sql-s        1433/udp
ms-sql-m        1434/tcp                        # Microsoft SQL Monitor
ms-sql-m        1434/udp
```

The "Microsoft SQL Monitor" is the DAC connection.

The log also shows similar information,

```
spid19s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv6> 1433].
spid19s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv4> 1433].
Server      Server is listening on [ ::1 <ipv6> 1434].
Server      Server is listening on [ 127.0.0.1 <ipv4> 1434].
```